# Could empty class be the right choice in some cases?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, oop

I have three classes ClassB , ClassC and ClassD are derived from ClassA class (which is an empty class).

I'm created WCF Services with one [operation contract] called GetInformation based on the type of object , the pararmter for this method is complex object ClassA.

When i call WCF object i intialies ClassA object by one of three classes (ClassB, ClassC or ClassD).

I know it's generally a design flaw to have an empty class, but could it be the best choice in my case or what's the best design for this scnario?

ClassA  is an empty super class 
Here is my code

```
[KnownType(typeof(ClassB))]
[KnownType(typeof(ClassC)))]
[KnownType(typeof(ClassD))]
[DataContract]
public class ClassA
{
}
```

ClassB is an derived from ClassA

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassB: ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public int num1{ set; get; }
}
```

ClassC is an derived from ClassA

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassC: ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public int num1{ set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public int num2{ set; get; }
}
```

ClassD is an derived from ClassA

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassD: ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public string val1{ set; get; }
}
```

GetInformation return Message based on the type of object

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetInformation(ClassA object);
}
```

Comment: Not only is that an anti-pattern for software design, it's particularly bad when the target in question represents a remote service, WCF or otherwise.  You never know what is an acceptable request.  Don't use polymorphism in the request parameter as it is a lose contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create empty class.

As the three classes **ClassB**, **ClassC** and **ClassD** do not have any common methods or properties.

So you may create an **Operation contract** for each class:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetInformationB(ClassB objectB);

   [OperationContract]
    string GetInformationC(ClassC objectC);

   [OperationContract]
    string GetInformationD(ClassD objectD);
}
```

Comment: _"do not have any common methods or properties"_ - actually Vitality demonstrated  `ClassC` could be inherited from `ClassB` with some refactoring

Comment: but still no need to do it i thisk, is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement interface for yours class. What was write for you sjb-sjb. 
But i see, you use classes without any common methods, or  property. Only

```
public class ClassC: ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public int num1{ set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public int num2{ set; get; }
}
```

and

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassB: ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public int num1{ set; get; }
}
```

you can rewrite it like this :

```
public class ClassC: ClassB
    { 
        [DataMember]
        public int num2{ set; get; }
    }
```

It`s can be problem in design your applications.
And try use composition instead inheritanse, or interfaces. Why?
You can read about it in this post:

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260343/why-is-inheritance-generally-viewed-as-a-bad-thing-by-oop-proponents

or there:

> https://codeburst.io/inheritance-is-evil-stop-using-it-6c4f1caf5117

Comment: the requirement is implement WFC Service with one method for inquiry, the client can inquiry using three different ways but the method it make the same work with different pararmter for example can inquiry about person information using id or name or sometimes birthofdate. 
Is it better to do three [operation contract] one for each pararmter nor the same way i have created, Take into consideration the method do the same job but with different paramters.

Comment: Sorry, i don`t understand you enough, you say about same work with different operators?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Not only is that an anti-pattern for software design, it's particularly bad when the target in question represents a remote service, WCF or otherwise.  You never know what is an acceptable request